# How to execute SQL verbatim?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
db.execute(sql)
```

`sql` contains the character sequence `%s`. This makes SQLAlchemy raise an exception because I don't provide any parameters. Is it possible to make SQLAlchemy pass `sql` verbatim to the database without trying to substitute any parameters, so that the database also receives the character sequence `%s`?

<sup>Disclaimer: I am totally aware of how SQL injection works and I know what I'm doing; this isn't an issue.</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sqlalchemy.text`:

```
db.execute(sqlalchemy.text(sql))
```